# Compare 2 large DATA tables(70k Records)

Tags: c#, datatable, comparison

How do I compare 2 large DATA tables in C#? The `DataTable.Select` method takes forever.

I need to compare each record’s field value with the other table. The source and target field data type might be different, e.g. Table1’s field1 data type is INT and Table2’s field1 datatype is VARCHAR.

Comment: Naive approach (*nested loops*) will take `70k * 70k == 4.9e9` iterations, which can take minutes if not hours to complete. Convert table into `Dictionary<K,V>` in order to have just `70k` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to profile application to find what exactly is slow: iterating through columns and comparing values or finding matching records (rows) that needs to be compared.

As for record, solution could be to convert a table to dictionary. That works if your tables have unique column, then you can convert them to dictionary, where key is unique column value for record and value is whole row. Then iterate first DataTable, get unique column value and get row from 2nd Datatable, but from Dictionary.

If issue is in comparison between 2 rows, then it is better to show the code to see, maybe there are extra comparisons or casts. It's hard to tell without code.